# have a Google Map V3, can't update map.setCenter from user input

Tags: google-maps, geocode

I'm new at this, but I have a Google V3 map that loads from the user's W3C browser geocode info, and I pull country, state, and city from the geocode object and update input boxes. If the user enters a street address, I want to geocode it via Google and change map.setCenter and setZoom, and display the updated map. When that works, I want to add a marker and infowindow. Despite hours of research and trials, I can't get the geocode and update to work. The Developer Tool in Chrome seems to indicate that execution ceases/fails at the geocoder.geocode line that is indicated in bold below. Here's relevant code.

```
var map, geocoder, marker, infowindow; //global variables

function initializeMap() {
// Try W3C Geolocation to geolocate desktop user
//initialize Google map, geolocate desktop user, and display after page loads
//find country, state, and city for the user's location  -  this all works
}
window.onload = initializeMap;

//change the Google Map after a user enters a street address
$("#streetAddress").blur(function() {
    //if state, city and street address locations are present
if ( $(this).val().length > 0 && $("#state").val().length > 0 && $("#city3").val().length > 0  ) {
    var gAddress =  [$(this).val() + ", " + $("#city3").val() + ", " + $("#state").val()] ;
    //get coordinates of this address
    //if no geocode object exists, create one
    if (!geocoder) {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); //create Geocoder object else use existing one from initializeMap() ?
    }       
    //create a GeocoderRequest object with user's street address
    var geoCoderRequest = {address:  gAddress} 
    //make a Geocoder request
    geocoder.geocode( geoCoderRequest, function(results, status) {  **//this line fails**
    //check if status is OK
            if ( status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            //update center of existing map on location returned for this address
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(14);
            }   
    });         
    } else {
            return; //no action if gAddress is incomplete
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#GeocoderRequest), address should be a string, but you've created gAddress as an array.

Try:

```
var gAddress =  $(this).val() + ", " + $("#city3").val() + ", " + $("#state").val();
```

Update: in response to your wanting to make the zoom happen after the map has initially loaded (e.g in response to user input), here's a simple example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var start = 1;

    function initialize() {
        var homeLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.476706,0); // London

        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: homeLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    }

    function setZoom() {
        map.setZoom(18);
    }

    function setTimedZoom() {
        map.setZoom(start);

        start = start+1;
        if (start > 18) {
            start = 1;  // lets go round again and again; in reality you'd probably stop zooming at this point.
        }

        setTimeout(setTimedZoom, 3000);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="javascript:setZoom()">Zoom In</a>
    <a href="javascript:setTimedZoom()">Timed</a>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes and thank you. This is very helpful. The code now executes properly down through the 'if status == OK' and I get an OK, but it does not setCenter to the user input address or setZoom.

Comment: After some further work, it seems that a Google map cannot be updated. I haven't read that anywhere, but its the behavior I'm getting. When I create a new map (the same one as the first time, but with a geocode from the user's newly input address), it creates a new 'updated'  map. I have several other problems to solve, but I seem to be on the right track. It is odd that its possible to move the map around manually with the cursor, but apparently it is not possible to do this with update code.

Comment: Must be something wrong with your code, I've not had problems updating an existing map to change center or zoom

Comment: hmmm. The 2 functions above are the only 2 places I have map code. The first function is copied from Google documentation. The variables, map and geocode, are global so the second function can access them. Do you see another error? Do you know a tutorial that does this. I've done days of searching, thinking, and trials and have not found the recipe. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Suggest using console.log and firebug to see exactly what's going on with your geocoder request

Comment: First,thanks. I restructured my code and it runs 50% faster to pop the map. But I still don't think it is possible to refresh a map without issuing the google.maps.Map() statement another time, after the initial load. As a test, I tried incrementing the zoom in the myOptions object that maps.Map() uses. Rather than zoom: 9, I used zoom: (9 + setInterval( function(){3}, 20000)), which should zoom in 3 steps every 20 seconds. The map loads late with zoom: 12. The initial load at 9 does not happen, and no repeats happen. Another maps.Map statement works, but refreshes of 1 statement do not work.

Comment: Bottom line: after a map loads, you can manually click zoom on the initial map.Maps() statement, but my test says this is not possible with code. In code, if you want to zoom in, it requires re-executing a map.Map() statement - somewhere.

Comment: Instead of doing zoom: x + setTimeout(y) you should do setTimeout(function() { map.setZoom(x+y)}.  I'll try and post up some code to illustrate this later